# Twitter Like Software for Corporations

Tags: twitter, blogging

Is there microblogging software that companies can host internally?  I think I remember Joel Spolsky mentioning that Fog Creek uses one.  I can't remember what the name was or find what other software is out there.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The software that [Joel Spolsky mentioned in the Stack Overflow Podcast](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W26423) was Laconica which has become [StatusNet](http://status.net/).

Answer (score 5):

If you want one that is just for your employees, but not hosted by you, look at [Yammer](http://www.yammer.com). It's free for basic functionality but there are [enterprise plans](https://www.yammer.com/about/pricing) which add features.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be one: [Status.net](http://status.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [P2](http://p2theme.com/) -- based on WordPress and the automattic team [seems to dig it](http://ma.tt/2009/05/how-p2-changed-automattic/) (granted, they built it...).  Check out [buddyPress](http://buddypress.org/) if you want to get even fancier and more "social".

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Incentive/features](http://www.incentivecorp.com/features), built with activity streams, dashboards, wikis, blogs, and search. Host internally.